# php security - including SQL username and password in php file

Tags: php, sql

I have a website that uses php to access an SQL database. It works fine and I have added various checks to make sure the user is logged in to access the required webpages etc and I am happy with that.

My question is, when they get to the reporting part of the website that uses php to access the SQL database the database username and password are passed in the php file:

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$con = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
```

Is this bad practice - is there a security risk? And if so what are the ways around it?

Many thanks

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_` functions. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_`. See http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: If someone gains access to your server to get that password then you have bigger problems. Your bigger security risk is using mysql_* functions.

Comment: your way is mayor practice ... it is ok ... better way (practice) is to store your access data outside your document root and include it via php ... but your way is ok (but consider the hint vrom zdhickman)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to place password on same folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344951/is-it-safe-to-place-password-on-same-folder)

Comment: Thanks for your comments - really useful and much appreciated. Just out of interest is the reason to come away from mysql because it is being depreciated and rather than a security reason?

Comment: Im pretty sure that having password as the password is a security flaw :)

Comment: @RichardGriffiths See this question as to why to move away from mysql_ for security reasons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Since the php is rendered on the server, the username and password cannot be seen by visitors to the page.  So storing the data on the php page is not a bad practice.  The only way to see the username and password is if someone got access to the server to view the files.

Another way is to have a config file that can be read by php but is outside of the public folders for the site.

Comment: Thank you - reassuring and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Soring the database login information within a php file is good practice and quite common. It is not possible for visitors to view this information, as the code is parsed before the page is sent to the user. As an additional level of security, it is good practice to configure the database to prohibit external access if it's on the same server.